# How to check internet connection globally and show no connection screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, connectivity

I use [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) package in my project to check internet connection.

File `main.dart` code:

```
StreamProvider<ConnectivityResult>(
    create: (context) =>
        InternetConnectionService().connectionStatusController.stream,
    child: MaterialApp(
.....
```

And on each screen I check internet connection like this:

```
bool hasConnection;

void checkConnectivity(context) async {
  var connectivityResult = Provider.of<ConnectivityResult>(context);
  if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none ||
      connectivityResult == null) {
    setState(() {
      hasConnection = false;
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      hasConnection = true;
    });
  }
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  checkConnectivity(context);
  return hasConnection == true 
    ? Scaffold() 
    : NoInternetScreen();
}
```

How I check connection globally instead on each screen from root or one widget and show no connection screen?

Comment: can't you put `checkConnectivity` in main file?

Comment: Yes I can do it @JohnJoe In this case will work from anywhere? How I must do it can you show example?

Comment: yes, will work from anywhere. Just use the widget build code you provided on each screen to your main file .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your MaterialApp widget, there is a builder. You can wrap your paths in any widget using the builder. Try doing this:

```
MaterialApp(
    ...
    builder: (context, child) {
        return StreamBuilder<ConnectivityResult>(
            stream: InternetConnectionService().connectionStatusController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                final conenctivityResult = snapshot.data;
                if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none || connectivityResult == null) return NoInternetScreen();

                return child;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Now you don't have to add any internet logic in other files. You can simply write your build methods excluding them.

Comment: Nice answer, how we could do the same with MaterialApp.router? I'm still figuring out ..

Comment: Material app router also has builder property. You can use it

Comment: stream: InternetConnectionService().connectionStatusController.stream,
@AfridiKayal it gives me error

Comment: Try this : WORKED SOLUTION

builder: (context, child) {
          return StreamBuilder<ConnectivityResult>(
              stream: Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                final conenctivityResult = snapshot.data;
                if (conenctivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none ||
                    conenctivityResult == null) {
                  return  NoInternetConnection();
                }

                return child!;
              });
        }

Answer (score 2):

```
       class ConnectivityUtils {
          static Future<bool> hasConnection() async {
            var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
            return connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile || connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi;
         } 
       }
```

You can use this class, and you can call `hasConnection()` before calling API
If it is false, you can show the No Connection Screen